# Any good offline mapping API for iOS besides ArcGIS?

Tags: ios, google-maps, arcgis

Does any one about powerful mapping API for iOS besides ArcGIS which has the capability to cache maps for offline viewing ? I have been searching but everywhere I go I find ArcGIS API for iOS. That API is definitely good but it doesnot provide the capability to cache map data into tiles for offline viewing.
Also does google map API support offline viewing?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[MapBox](https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-ios-sdk/) supports [offline tile caching](https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-ios-sdk/#tile_caching__class).

Comment: Mapbox is nothing when compared to ArcGIS. It only has 3 basemaps which are highly priced and doesnot even support bing basemaps